# NIFI - https site-to-site PeerSelector connection refuse

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a standalone nifi running inside the the eks cluster and it is exposed through loadbalancer service on port tcp-443 that point to container port 8443 and other nifi is on ec2 instance tries to push template in eks nifi but getting following error:

```
WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient Penalizing a peer Peer[url=https://nifi-deployment-6d64f9c557-9nbr9:9443/nifi-api] due to java.net.UnknownHostException: nifi-deployment-6d64f9c557-9nbr9
2020-05-14 17:14:02,755 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.n.r.util.SiteToSiteRestApiClient Failed to create transaction for https://nifi-deployment-6d64f9c557-9nbr9:9443/nifi-api/data-transfer/input-ports/11c08e25-0172-1000-155f-5c082bd0bca8/transactions
java.net.UnknownHostException: nifi-deployment-6d64f9c557-9nbr9
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:664)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:635)
at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:474)
at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.lease(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:280)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:295)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.requestConnection(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:377)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:129)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:68)
at org.apache.nifi.remote.util.SiteToSiteRestApiClient.initiateTransactionForSend(SiteToSiteRestApiClient.java:640)
at org.apache.nifi.remote.util.SiteToSiteRestApiClient.initiateTransaction(SiteToSiteRestApiClient.java:474)
at org.apache.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient.createTransaction(HttpClient.java:175)
at org.apache.nifi.remote.StandardRemoteGroupPort.onTrigger(StandardRemoteGroupPort.java:225)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.AbstractPort.onTrigger(AbstractPort.java:244)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient Penalizing a peer Peer[url=https://nifi-deployment-6d64f9c557-9nbr9:9443/nifi-api] due to java.net.UnknownHostException: nifi-deployment-6d64f9c557-9nbr9
INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.nifi.remote.client.http.HttpClient Couldn't find a valid peer to communicate with."
```

2020-05-12 15:16:54,598 WARN [Http Site-to-Site PeerSelector] o.apache.nifi.remote.client.PeerSelector org.apache.nifi.remote.c

Ssl handshank is also successful.[image: site-site]

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace from the log and a more complete network description with the relevant hostnames. The current information is insufficient to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank for reply for your reference added logs and screenshort of error

Comment: You should check the networking configuration. The NiFi instance is unable to resolve the remote hostname to connect to it. Try getting shell access to the NiFi instance and running command line tools to connect to that host, or use fully qualified domain names.